# How to set the variable "app" in Rack Test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, rack-test

I have an Rack app:

```
def app
   Rack::Builder.new{
      run MyApp
    }.to_app
end
```

This works fine, but I want to change `app` to something else, because there is an model named App.

How to set Rack Test to run against an app with another name?

Working in RSpec. Changing the app results in:

```
NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `app' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Request:0x007fa76f937ba0>
```

Comment: If `app` is a keyword in the framework, why fight the framework.  Does 'app' really appropriately describe the model?  I can think of no natural word that is 'app'  where I would not wonder what it is short for.  Though, I am not a linguist.

Comment: Apps are what are installed on Android devices. For our context, it is the best name for the model. Applications, in contrast, would have multiple meanings. Besides, I am working with an existing database, so I don't have the option to change the name of the model.